# Finding first occurrence formula not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

My data range is `G192:J195` and the search value is in cell `J190`.

The Formula I'm trying is:

```
=INDEX($G$192:$G$195,MATCH(J190,(OFFSET($H$192:$J$195,,{0,1,2})),0))
```

The formula is in cell `K192`.

The error I get is`#N/A`.

NB: The purpose of using Offset function is to search in all 3 Columns at once.

[image]

Comment: It looks like OFFSET() can handle a 1-dimensional array, but not 2.  The result of the OFFSET function here is the array {135,127,126}.  You can see the intermediate result of the OFFSET portion by [selecting it and hitting f9](https://exceljet.net/tips/how-to-check-and-debug-a-formula-with-f9).

Comment: Have a look at [How to return a result's position in a 2D array?](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/516742-how-return-results-position-2d-array-3.html); last answer on p3